# How To Remove Duplicates in Datatable it contains single column only?

Tags: c#, datatable, notepad

Here i upload one Notepad file in Datatable.it contains only phone numbers and doesnot contain any Headers.so i want to Remove the duplicates from My Datatable.it contains single column only.
When i do this i get the result but one value will be Duplicated.

```
9988775566
9988556644
9966332200
9988775566
```

like this one value will get again.i want to get the Datatable with out Duplicates.
My Snippet is

```
public void duplicatesinnotepad(DataTable dt, string col)
    {
        ArrayList unique = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList duplicat = new ArrayList();
        foreach (DataRow de in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (unique.Contains(de[col]))
                duplicat.Add(de);
            else
                unique.Add(de[col]);
        }
        foreach (DataRow de in duplicat)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(de);  
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

using Linq To Get Distinct Elements

```
        var list = (  
        from row in dt.AsEnumerable()  
        select row.Field<string>("contacts")).Distinct();
```

OR

```
    var list = dt.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(item => item.Field<string>(dt.Columns["contacts"]));
```

Comment: Here i dont use any database..and i dont have column name also

Comment: what i mean is when i download a file it does not contain any column headers

Comment: @Raamraj put Your code how you created that `DataTable dt`

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("contacts");
                TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath);
                string line;
                if ((line = tr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
                {
                    string[] items = line.Trim().Split(',', ';', '\n');
                    foreach (string str in items)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["contacts"] = str;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }  Here i created column name like "columns"

Comment: @Raamraj so `contacts` is name of Column i updated above code

Comment: but i don`t want to display column  namein download file.